# JTextfields within a java GUI that update?

Tags: java

I created a Java gui that displays a circle with a JSlider that can be moved from left to right and changes the size of the circle. Everything runs with no errors. My issue is getting a JTextfield that would display the area, diameter, radius, etc.. of the circle and updates it when the JSlider is moved. I have one main class and two sub-classes. I didn't put the main since it's not important.

Here's what I have"

```css
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

public class SliderFrame extends JFrame
{
      private JSlider diameterJSlider;
      private OvalPanel myPanel;

      public SliderFrame()
      {

        super("Circle");

        myPanel = new OvalPanel();
        myPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        
      

        diameterJSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 200, 10);
        diameterJSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        diameterJSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        diameterJSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
        {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
          myPanel.setDiameter(diameterJSlider.getValue());
        }
      }
    );
        add(diameterJSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     }
  }



import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OvalPanel extends JPanel
{
      private int diameter = 10;
          

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         
         g.drawOval(30, 30, diameter, diameter);
      }

      public void setDiameter(int newDiameter)
      {
          diameter = (newDiameter >= 0 ? newDiameter: 10 );
           repaint();
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize()
      {
         return new Dimension(200, 200);
      }
      public Dimension getMinimumSize()
      {
         return getPreferredSize();
      }
  }
```

Comment: So add a JTextField to your SliderFrame and when stateChanged is called, update its text, seems simple to me. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can't understand why you don't just add the JTextField to the panel add set its Text as Slider moves?

Comment: I don't know which class I should add it too.

Comment: `display.setText( "Radius: "+ "\nDiameter: " + "\nArea: " + "\nCircumference: "` I tried this but it doesn't update automatically.

Comment: @Killer066: Generally, you would have 3 JTextFields with JLabels to display 3 values.

Comment: I just want an example code I code to help me with the JTextFields.